# Example of application of hilbert-schmidt norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

I'm pretty new to linear algebra, and am learning about norms. I'm having trouble understanding how to apply the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

How would you do it for a simple example like $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: You may find [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matrices the Hilbert-Schmidt norm is just $$\|(a_{j,k})\|_{HS} = \sqrt{\sum_{j,k=1}^n |a_{j,k}|^2}.$$
In your example this results in $\sqrt{2}$.